# Axios ERR_NETWORK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using axios with this request code in reactJS

```js
import axios from 'axios';

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  // i have pro API KEY so i can't put it here :-)
  headers: { 
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MYAPIKEY'
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

but I'll get `ERR_NETWORK` error

where is my problem?

Comment: Ur code is fine.
This works for me, but i take 401 error without API key.

Comment: It works. I tried with your api key

Comment: @HeetVakharia why doesn't work for me?

Comment: Try [these](https://www.techbout.com/err-network-changed-chrome-error-39393/) steps, it might work or try in a different browser